# How to downgrade project from sdk 23 to sdk 22 in Android studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

Previously I used android studio 1.3 but I got some message about new version of android studio a couple of times. So I decided to update the android studio to new version 1.4. After updating it, I got these error for my gradle file:

```
D:\..\hamrahsalamat-payesh\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
'C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mhealth.healthnotation"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.0.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

After some search I found out android studio uses sdk 23 by default from version 1.4. **however I don't want to use sdk 23 because I have some deprecated methods and at this time I don't have enough time to replace and fix them.** So how could I make it to use sdk 22?

I saw in some post that I could delete `23.0.1` and `23.0.0` folders from `C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7`and `C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7` and delete also from `maven-metadata.xml` file, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

> After some search I found out android studio uses sdk 23 by default from version 1.4.

That is for new projects.

> So how could I make it to use sdk 22?

You already are, via `compileSdkVersion 22`.

Comment: yes, according to gradle file the project uses sdk 22 but android studio gives some error because of compiling with sdk 23!!! Before updating android studio i didn't have any problem.

Comment: @Taher: "android studio gives some error because of compiling with sdk 23" -- no, it "gives some error" because for some reason you are pulling in `appcompat-v7:23.0.0`. You might want to run a Gradle dependencies report to determine what is causing your builds to pull in the newer version of `appcompat-v7`, since your `build.gradle` is requesting `appcompat-v7:22.2.0`.

Comment: Thanks,but how I could run a Gradle dependencies report? I can't figure it out why it want to compile with newer version while I have deleted any thing about sdk 23 from  sdk folder!!!

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_dependencies

Comment: I've never used gradle in command line and I am really confused with that user guide. I downloaded gradle-2.7-all.zip and extract it and add path to envirenment variable. Now the cmd knows gradle command but I can't run anything. I run this code `gradle -q dependencies payesh:dependencies webapp:dependencies` but it can't find my project because I don't now where is root project!!!

Comment: @Taher: Your project root is wherever `D:\..\hamrahsalamat-payesh` is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92058/discussion-between-taher-and-commonsware).